Terminology for computation vs. output
Is there a widely accepted name and/or notation for the computational process of an algorithm as opposed to its output? To clarify, suppose I have an algorithm $A$, and I denote as $A(x)$ the output of $A$ on input $x$. I wish to analyze the operation of $A$ on input $x$ (analyze the intermediate values of variables, for example). Repeatedly saying "as $A$ runs on $x$" or something along these lines is very verbose. Any suggestions?

People often talk about the "computation history" or "computation tableau" or, as you said, the "run of A on input x"

You might also look at the papers on the simplex method being NP-mighty and PSPACE-mighty, since those notions are about the run of the algorithm rather than its output.

Is that a well-defined concept? Can I say something like A is the computation history of A on input x?

Execution trace.

Yes. I mean, you should define it so it's clear in what sense you are using it, but yes it's well defined. The sequence of configurations of the Turing machine A (or whatever computational formalism - in TMs the config includes the tapes and all) when run on input x.

Thanks Joshua and Andrej. This has been very helpful.
